# Identifying German soldier in WWII from single photo?

Tags: germany, world-war-2, photo-identification, austria

[image]

I found out that my grandfather was actually a German soldier in WWII who was in Austria in the year of 1945 but I only have a photograph and no other information.

Is there any way I can search for his identity?

Comment: Do you have a name?

Comment: Before posting a name be aware of our privacy policy in the [help] because this man *may* be living and from photo may have been born around 1920-1925 (< 100 years ago).

Comment: According to the uniform he was part of the air force (Luftwaffe) with rank Private (Gefreiter). The shoulder strap should show the identification of the unit which is not visible on the photo. From http://www.wehrmacht-lexikon.de/luftwaffe/dienstgradabzeichen/verbaende/rangabzeichen.php.